# About using multiprocessing to read file

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have many files in the folders,so I think I should use multiprocess ,
then I use multiprocess to read txt file in the folder,
But I compare the time if I used multiprocess or not ,
I found if I don't use pool is more fast. I don't know why ,
so what situation should I use Pool to read file( huge files?)

```
using Pool
time:0.5836s
not using Pool
time:0.0076s
```

the code is ,

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool
import glob2,os,time

class PandasReadFile:

    def __init__(self):
        print('123')

    def readFilePool(self,path):
        n,t=0,time.time()
        print(t)
        pp = Pool(processes=1)

        # here is using pool
        df = pd.concat(pp.map(self.read_csv, glob2.iglob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))))
        # not using pool
        # df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob2.iglob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))))
        t = time.time() - t
        print('%.4fs' % (t))
        print(df)

    @staticmethod
    def read_csv(filename):
        return pd.read_csv(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = PandasReadFile()
    p.readFilePool('D:/')
```

Comment: The actual work you are doing takes only 0.0076 seconds!  The overhead of creating an additional Python interpreter in a separate process is more than this.  Do you have a real use case which takes longer?  Can you test that instead?

Comment: the test I just put 10 files in the folder ,
If I have huge numbers of files , does multiprocessing faster than single ?
and if yes , how many process should I create ? thanks.

Comment: I/O bound operations will not require access to the global interpreter lock. multiprocessing.Process will be faster here.

Comment: most of the time those operations are I/O bound. Multiprocessing won't help much. Multithreading helps the same in those cases and it's simpler to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spawn as many processes as you want but since you work on the same hard drive, you won't reduce time. Worse: you will loose time.

You can use multiprocessing for CPU-intensive tasks, not for IO-intensive tasks.

You may reduce time with two processes if you copy files from one drive to another. It may also work with mounted network drives (NAS).